# How to click the below shown icon using Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have attached a screenshot of a Stackoverflow page.

How to click it with Python Selenium?

[image: reference the image to identify what I am pointing to]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the *notification icon* you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193625/how-to-click-on-a-element-through-selenium-python/54194511#54194511) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "svg.svg-icon.iconInbox"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[local-name()='svg' and @class='svg-icon iconInbox']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 1):

That's an SVG element, and I do see that the class `svg-icon iconInbox` is unique in nature, so the below XPath should work for you.

```
//*[name()='svg' and @class='svg-icon iconInbox']
```

and using explicit wait, you can perform click like this:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[name()='svg' and @class='svg-icon iconInbox']"))).click()
    print('Clicked on the button')
except:
    print('Could not click ')
    pass
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 1):

The selector for the Stack Overflow inbox is `"svg.iconInbox"`.

You can verify that directly from the console with:

`document.querySelector("svg.iconInbox")`

Add that to a click method in a Selenium framework, and you can click it. Eg, here's how to click it using [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase):

```py
self.click("svg.iconInbox")
```